# How do I convert string to a uint32 and send it to server in Lua?

Tags: tcp, lua

I want to use lua to send tcp messages to the server. The server requests to send a little-endian uint32 byte stream to it. But my lua doesn't have string.pack and string.unpack. How to achieve it with only lua but not c?

My opinion is:
1.converts not in uint32 format to uint32

```
function UIUtils.GetStr2ID(strID)
    return (string.byte(strID, 1) << 24) | (string.byte(strID, 2) << 16) | (string.byte(strID, 3) << 8) | (string.byte(strID, 4))
end
```

2.change it to little-endian

I want to know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear. Do you want:

1. Conversion from number ("uint32") to bytestring (little endian? network byte order usually is big endian)
2. Conversion from (little endian) bytestring to number ("uint32")
3. Conversion from big endian to little endian byte strings and vice versa can trivially be done using `str:reverse()` where `str` is a string.

#### Number to Bytestring

Output is a little endian 4-byte-string.

```lua
local floor = math.floor
local function uint32_to_bytestr(n)
    assert(n % 1 == 0 and n >= 0 and n < 2^32, "n does not fit in a uint32")
    return ("%c%c%c%c"):format(
        n % 0x100,
        floor(n / 0x100) % 0x100,
        floor(n / 0x10000) % 0x100,
        floor(n / 0x1000000) % 0x100
    )
end
```

#### Bytestring to Number

Input is a little endian 4-byte-string, output is a number from `0` to `2^32-1`.

```lua
local function bytestr_to_uint32(str)
    assert(#str == 4, "byte string is not 4 bytes long")
    return str:byte(1)
         + str:byte(2) * 0x100
         + str:byte(3) * 0x10000
         + str:byte(4) * 0x1000000
end
```

Comment: Yes！Thanks for your answer and please excuse my problem description.My English is not good.I have another question, what should I do if I want to convert all non-uint32 bits into unit32?

Comment: @sp1ke what do you mean? There is a "bytes to uint" conversion in my answer.